# Adobe CQ / AEM Client Lib channel property interaction with cq:includeClientLib tag

Tags: jsp, adobe, aem

I am working on improving page performance in adobe cq and I've seen various sites([1](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/developing/components/clientlibs.html), [2](http://www.wemblog.com/2012/01/how-to-use-and-debug-cq-client-library.html)) which mention the **channels** property for nodes of type **cq:ClientLibraryFolder**

I've set up a small example with 2 components (***cmpA*** and ***cmpB***). Both have a **categories** value of ***cmps.cmp*** and are in the **apps** directory. I then created another node of type **cq:ClientLibraryFolder** in the **etc** folder that has an embed property of ***cmps.cmp*** and a categories property with value ***cmps.all***

In my view, I have the following which results in a concatenated css file from both the components css in their respective client lib folder.

```
<cq:includeClientLib css="cmps.all" />
```

When I add **!touch** as the **channels** property of ***cmpB*** then override the userAgent in chrome to iPhone, the css for ***cmpB*** is still concatenated.

1. localhost:4502/libs/cq/ui/content/dumplibs.html verifies the channels property is set to !touch
2. I've confirmed the current channel is **touch** by adding a console.log inside of *etc/clientlibs/foundation/librarymanager/DefaultChannelDetector.js*
3. Adding ?debug=true while loading the clientlibs.css in the url confirms the css from both clientlibs is included

I'd like to use the channels property to phase out certain css (and eventually js) files given certain use cases, while not overcomplicating the markup with extra logic as the documentation vaguely suggests. I aim for my end result to be a single css file (minified and gzipped via the Day CQ HTML Library Manager in the Config Manager(server/system/console/configMgr).

Am I using the channels property incorrectly? Is it even meant to be used in the way that I'm using it? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `channels` property has to be set on the clientlib node. if you wanted special css/js for a particular channel, you would need to create at least 2 clientlibs:

1. first clientlib would have `categories=[cmps.all]`
2. second clientlib would have `categories=[cmps.all]` and `channels=[!touch]`

the first one would always load for cmps.all while the second would only load for non-touch channels.

Comment: Thank you Kaiser, I was setting it on sub-clientlib nodes and the embed node was picking them all up anyways.

For other users, my current setup is
cmpA with categories=[cmps.cmpA]
cmpB with categories=[cmps.cmpB]
global with categories=[cmps.all], embed=[cmps.cmpA]
touch with categories=[cmps.all], channels=[touch], embed=[cmps.cmpB]

Then the <cq:includeClientLib css="cmps.all" /> will load exactly what I need.